# How does org-mode implement syntax highlighting for code blocks?

Tags: org-mode, syntax-highlighting

How does org-mode implement syntax highlighting for code blocks? More specifically, for a C file, does it use `cc-mode` or does it have its own algorithm? For example, if I have this org file: **test.org**:

```
* Example source code in C: 

#+BEGIN_SRC c
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    printf( "Hello world\n" );
    return 0;
}
#+END_SRC
```

I get the following highlighting:

[image]

---

But if have the same pure C file (using `cc-mode`) **test.c**:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    printf( "Hello world\n" );
    return 0;
}
```

I get:

---

[image]

---

Notice that `printf` has different face color in the two files. So it seems like `org-mode` has its own syntax highlighting. It is not using `cc-mode` to do the highlighting, is that correct?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It uses cc-mode.

It copes the text to a temporary buffer, highlights it using the major mode that is associated with the language, and copies back the highlighting.

In addition, it makes everything not highlighted grey. In addition to the difference you spotted in `printf`, this is also visible in other places like the braces and parentheses.

Comment: Where could one find the source code for org mode doing this? I understand it's probably hairy, but a pointer to some part of it would be much appreciated. Looking to implement something similar for a minor mode in a completely different context (lit-html)

Comment: Check out `org-src.el`. I found `org-src-font-lock-fontify-block` enlightening. See how it's used in `org.el` in `org-fontify-meta-lines-and-blocks-1`. In Emacs you can do `C-h f org-src-font-lock-fontify-block RET` and tab to the link for the installed source code or [find it on Org Mode's Gogs hosting](https://code.orgmode.org/bzg/org-mode/src/release_9.3.6/lisp/org-src.el#L565).