# Syntax highlighting for source blocks inside special blocks

Tags: org-mode, syntax-highlighting, doom

Syntax highlighting doesn't work for source blocks that are nested inside special blocks:

```
#+BEGIN_test
#+begin_src js
return 14
#+end_src

#+RESULTS:
: 14
#+END_test

#+begin_src js
return 14
#+end_src

#+RESULTS:
: 14
```

[image]

Above the cursor, I have a source block inside a special whose syntax is not highlighted. The same block below the cursor is highlighted correctly.

Is there a way to get the syntax highlighting inside nested source blocks?

I found an [answer](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/54511) on how syntax highlighting works in EMACS. It is fine with me if there is a way to manually do this process to get syntax highlighting inside nested source blocks.